# EJB 3.1 remove invocation context for security purpose (ThreadLocal, ...)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.1

I have a webapp on one Glassfish server (front-end) and an EJB 3.1 app (back-end) on another Glassfish server. The webapp communicates with the EJB 3.1 via remote invocation.

I would like to pass context data (user data i.e.) without having to define it as an input parameter of each business operation.

I have one idea, but not sure it will work: use a **ThreadLocal** to store data, but the **ThreadLocal** will only be available on one server (meaning JVM) => use the **InvocationContext** object and create interceptor to add user data to the **ContextData** Map.

What do you think about it? Any other ideas are more than welcome! ;-)

**UPDATE**

After first answer, I googled it a little bit and found the annotation **@CallerPrincipal**.

How can I set this object before the remote invocation?

Answer (score 2):

The container will already handle this so you don't have to code it yourself.

In your EJB, you can access the EJBContext, which has a [getCallerPrincipal()](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/ejb/EJBContext.html#getCallerPrincipal%28%29) method which will give you the callers identity.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But how can I "set" the calle principal to the EJBContext?

Comment: You don't, it will be set by whatever authentication mechanism you use in your web app.  Once logged in, the container will pass identity.